# Handle facebook login window close action

Tags: jquery, openfb

I am using openFB for facebook login.

```
openFB.login(
            function(response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    // do something
                } else {
                    console.log('Facebook login failed');
                }
            }
        )
```

This opens the login window.
How can I handle an event when the user closes this window without signing in?

Comment: create a click handler for the closing element and do your stuff in the handler

Comment: Since this works by implementing the manual login flow, by opening the FB login dialog in a popup window, I think that might not be possible at all – that popup contains content from a different domain, so the Same Origin Policy prevent you from interacting with its content. The `Window.closed` property of the popup could perhaps be watched via in a timer interval – but that would have to be implemented inside the openFB code directly then.

Comment: thats really weird. there is no FB event handler?